# How do I split multi-lines (comma-containing) string from txt file on python2

Tags: python

I'm really new on Python so I need your help

I have a text like this:

```
19 , 22.3 ,22.24 , 79 , 40.764767 ,29.932207  
1 , 24.38 ,24.50 , 586 , 40.762291 ,29.919300  
11 , 23.13 ,23.24 , 105 , 40.763786 ,29.929407  
12 , 22.38 ,23.56 , 71 , 40.765610 ,29.941540  
5 , 23.2 ,24.15 , 173 , 40.763805 ,29.929356
```

I tried to split:

```
array = file.read().split(",")
```

but result was like so

```
['19 ', ' 22.3 ', '22.24 ', ' 79 ', ' 40.764767 ', '29.932207  \n1 ',
 ' 24.38 ', '24.50 ', ' 586 ', ' 40.762291 ', '29.919300  \n11 ', ' 23.13 ',
'23.24 ', ' 105 ', ' 40.763786 ', '29.929407  \n12 ', ' 22.38 ', '23.56 ', 
' 71 ', ' 40.765610 ', '29.941540  \n5 ', ' 23.2 ', '24.15 ', ' 173 ',
 ' 40.763805 ', '29.929356 \n']
```

But I want to make it without '\n' because after split operation , I have to return string to int . So how can I make it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
x="""19 , 22.3 ,22.24 , 79 , 40.764767 ,29.932207
1 , 24.38 ,24.50 , 586 , 40.762291 ,29.919300
11 , 23.13 ,23.24 , 105 , 40.763786 ,29.929407
12 , 22.38 ,23.56 , 71 , 40.765610 ,29.941540
5 , 23.2 ,24.15 , 173 , 40.763805 ,29.929356  """
print re.split(r" *, *|\n", x)
```

You can do it in one go using `re`.

Output:`['19', '22.3', '22.24', '79', '40.764767', '29.932207', '1', '24.38', '24.50', '586', '40.762291', '29.919300', '11', '23.13', '23.24', '105', '40.763786', '29.929407', '12', '22.38', '23.56', '71', '40.765610', '29.941540', '5', '23.2', '24.15', '173', '40.763805', '29.929356  ']`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
array = [file.read().replace('\n','').split(',')]
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
array = [line.split(',') for line in file.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your text file has six floats per line.

If you want each line kept separate:

```
with open("path/to/file", "rt") as f:
    data = [ [float(v.strip()) for v in l.strip().split(',')] 
            for l in f]
```

If you just want an array containing all the numbers (i.e. ignoring line structure of file)

```
with open("path/to/file", "rt") as f:
    data = [ float(v.strip()) 
             for l in f 
             for v in l.strip().split(',')]
```